# Sorting out Django and MySQL in virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv

I'm following [this](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/) tutorial to get started with Django, but I'm very confused about how to integrate MySQL. Doing this in the context of virtualenv (which is new to me) seems to complicate things even further.

I'm running on Ubuntu and the MySQL server is on another host. Here are my specific questions:

1. What packages do I need to install and in what order?
2. Which packages should be installed while virtualenv is activated?
3. How do I know whether to use `pip`, `easy_install`, or `apt-get install`?
4. If I run any of the commands above while the virtualenv is activated, are they *only* installed in the virtualenv?
5. I seem to run into problems when I try to issue the above commands with `sudo`. I've avoided this issue by logging in as `root`. Is this to be expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to install the system library. This is global and does not happen inside a virtualenv.  If you have aptitude it is as easy as `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`
   this alos needs `libmysqlclient` (`libmysqlclient18 - MySQL database client library`) too.
2. after installing libmysqlclient and python-mysql using aptitude you can activate your virutualenv and install python-mysql package `pip install MySQL-python`.  This will make `MySQLdb` avaialable within your virtualenv
3. Mysql is a tricky package because it requires the mysql client libraries, which must be installed on your system.  the vast majority of python packages will be available on pip or through github (which you can easily install through pip) and will not require extra system packages.
4. if you `pip install` something while your virtualenv is active it will install it only into your virtual env.
5. You will probably need to run sudo to install system wide packages using `aptitude`.  Please don't log in as root, you can [grant your user sudo access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user-in-12-04)

THe good news is mysql is pretty much as difficult as it gets.  Almost all other python packages are as simples as activating your environment, and `pip install <pacakge_name>`

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing. I ran into one issue, though. When I run `sudo pip install MySQL-python` (with virtualenv activated) I get the following message: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. However, I noticed the path in the error message is not in my virtualenv. It looks like it's installed system-wide but not in my virtualenv?

Comment: if it is installed into /usr/lib then i'm guessing your virtualenv was not activated?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb installs mysql-python into the global space.

Comment: like @Evan Leis said, using sudo adds into global space, and not to the virtual env space  
I have mysql in global, and trying to  
pip install mysql-python  
gave error:  
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found  
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

1. `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`
2. `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`
3. `sudo apt-get install python-dev`
4. `pip install mysql-python` ( Inside your virtualenv )